# Scrollbar not working with mouse wheel and not styled properly

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, slickgrid

I have problem with scrollbar with an inner container. The main issue is that scrolling the mouse wheel only scrolls the outer scrollbar while I expect the inner scrollbar to scroll when I'm hover it and also why is the scrollbar styled differently (at least in Chrome, in Firefox it shows ok)?. I am not sure what is happening but I think it's caused by CSS somehow. I use Bootstrap framework (BS3 and BS4 both show the problem) and the row container has the following CSS

```css
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: block;
}
```

You can see from the print screen below that the scrollbar is styled differently (there's no top/bottom arrows at least in Chrome), I have no clue why and I didn't apply any styling to the scrollbar.

There's a live demo here [Angular-Slickgrid - Row Detail](https://ghiscoding.github.io/angular-slickgrid-demos/#/rowdetail), click on the "+" icon to open any of the row detail container. Also note that I'm the author of [Angular-Slickgrid](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid) (which is a wrapper library of [SlickGrid](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid)) and it's a library used by few hundred people.

However note that the same demo works in [SlickGrid - Row Detail](http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example16-row-detail.html) which basically the same demo but in plain html/css, it uses jQueryUI instead of Bootstrap.

[image: scrolling issue]

It might actually be Angular that cancels the scroll, I see this mousewheel event handler and if I remove it then it works

[image]

Comment: It's not Angular that cancels the scroll, it's `slick.grid.js`

Comment: I would rather be surprised if it's SlickGrid cancelling the scroll, what tells that it is coming from it? Would you mind sharing how you came to that conclusion? It could be an answer to the question

Comment: If you remove `mousewheel` `slick.grid.js` event handler it works. Also, click on the link `slick.grid.js:4393` you should see the function `handleMouseWheel(e, delta, deltaX, deltaY)` that causes the problem

Comment: I see yes you are completely right, thanks a lot for finding the issue